# How to fix 404 "The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts//SMS/Messages.json" not found error in Twilio-Connector in Ballerina

Tags: twilio-api, ballerina

I am creating a customer registration rest service using ballerina and the use case related to this is when the customer get registered successfully I need to send a sms to the customer.When I used the Twilio Connector in ballerina to send the sms I get the following error.

```
404 Not Found-:The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts//SMS/ 
Messages.json was not found.
```

Below shows the code related to the Twilio-integration,

```
import wso2/twilio;
twilio:Client twilioClient = new({
    accountSId: config:getAsString(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID),
    authToken: config:getAsString(TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
});
```

I have included Twilio-Sid and Auth Token inside the ballerina.conf file as well.Below shows the function which I have written to send sms through Twilio-connector

```
function sendSmsToCustomers(string mobile) returns boolean {

    boolean isSuccess= false;
    string toMobile = mobile;
    string messageBody = config:getAsString(TWILIO_MESSAGE);
    string fromMobile = config:getAsString(TWILIO_FROM_MOBILE);
    string message = messageBody;
    var response = twilioClient->sendSms(fromMobile, toMobile,  message);
   if (response is twilio:SmsResponse) {
        if (response.sid != EMPTY_STRING) {
            log:printDebug("Twilio Connector -> SMS successfully sent to " + toMobile);
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        log:printDebug("Twilio Connector -> SMS failed sent to " + toMobile);
        log:printError(<string>response.detail().message);
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

The expected output should be to send a sms to the provided mobile number(toMobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is **TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID** is not read from the *ballerina.conf* file.
The *ballerina.conf* file should have the configuration properties as follows, in order to match with your code.

```
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID="your_account_sid"
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN="your_auth_token"
TWILIO_MESSAGE="your_message"
TWILIO_FROM_MOBILE="your_from_mobile_number"
```

Comment: I have entered configurations in the ballerina.conf file, even when I remove the credentials, I get a different response as "401 Unauthorized -  : Authentication Error - No credentials provided ". so the problem doesn't lie on the credentials it seems but when accessing their resources. That's why I get "404 Not Found -  : The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts//SMS/Messages.json was not found 
" error.

Comment: Can you please try with a new pull of the package? I recently fixed a bug, but that may not be the case you get this error. Please try your code after executing following command. It will pull the latest module version.
`ballerina pull wso2/twilio`

Comment: Yes, issue was resolved after pulling the latest module version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issue.
What I found that in `Twilio/Rest/Client.php`
The constructor expects username, password and other details.

> public function __construct(string **$username** = null, string **$password** = null, string $accountSid = null, string $region = null, HttpClient $httpClient = null, array $environment = null)

But in the Twilio.php used for library loading, it is trying to create Client object by passing the SID and TOKEN.

So mostly likely, either the library code shared is incorrect or is of different version